# Transform a single random value to normally distributed one

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, transformation

Is there a (calculable) function that given a **single**, uniformly distributed random value `0 <= x < 1`, can "transform" it to a normally distributed value with mean `0` and standard deviation `1`?

If there's not an exact function, is there an approximation?

Comment: [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) is your friend.

Comment: @ivan But BMT works with 2 random values. I want just 1 input.

Comment: Then calculate the [inverse error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions). Though not elementary and not very practical, it surely is calculable via various series or something.

Comment: You should state that $x$ is *uniformly* distributed.

Comment: Why *inverse* in the title ?

Comment: @yves I have edited the question, which I think is clearer now. I invite you to make more edits as you like to make it more correct, especially the title and tags

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned by solving for $x$ equation $$\text{erf}(x)=a$$ you could be interested by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172474/erf-squared-approximation/1173081#1173081) where I proposed as an approximation
$$\mathrm{erf}\!\left(x\right)\approx\sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac 4 {\pi}\,\frac{1+\alpha\, x^2}{1+\beta\, x^2}\,x^2 \Big)}$$ where $$\alpha=\frac{10-\pi ^2}{5 (\pi -3) \pi }\qquad \text{and}\qquad \beta=\frac{120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2}{15 (\pi -3) \pi }$$
which then reduces to solve $$\log(1-a^2)=-\frac 4 {\pi}\,\frac{1+\alpha \,x^2}{1+\beta\, x^2}\,x^2$$ which is a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

For illustration purposes, I give below a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{erf}^{-1}(a) & \text{approx} \\
 0.05 & 0.044340 & 0.044340 \\
 0.10 & 0.088856 & 0.088856 \\
 0.15 & 0.133727 & 0.133727 \\
 0.20 & 0.179143 & 0.179143 \\
 0.25 & 0.225312 & 0.225312 \\
 0.30 & 0.272463 & 0.272463 \\
 0.35 & 0.320858 & 0.320858 \\
 0.40 & 0.370807 & 0.370807 \\
 0.45 & 0.422680 & 0.422681 \\
 0.50 & 0.476936 & 0.476937 \\
 0.55 & 0.534159 & 0.534161 \\
 0.60 & 0.595116 & 0.595120 \\
 0.65 & 0.660854 & 0.660861 \\
 0.70 & 0.732869 & 0.732883 \\
 0.75 & 0.813420 & 0.813449 \\
 0.80 & 0.906194 & 0.906253 \\
 0.85 & 1.017900 & 1.018030 \\
 0.90 & 1.163090 & 1.163390 \\
 0.95 & 1.385900 & 1.386820 \\ 
 0.96 & 1.452220 & 1.453450 \\
 0.97 & 1.534490 & 1.536190 \\
 0.98 & 1.644980 & 1.647550 \\
 0.99 & 1.821390 & 1.825990
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Maybe you should tell what the error function is and what is the connection of the inverse to the given problem. I am not sure that the OP is versed in these topics...

Comment: This is pretty good, but it produces only one side of the bell. Is there a tweak to produce a complete bell, ie as many negative results as positive ones? And @yves is correct, I am not versed in these topics.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It produces non-normal dist. Have I got it right: `sqrt(1-exp(-1.27323954474*x*x)*(1+0.0586276296*x*x)/(1+0.0886745239*x*x)))` ?

Comment: After testing using the code in my previous comment, the values produced are roughly "normalish", but the values are *all* within 0-1 like a half bell, but I anted a *sigma* of 1, not a max range of 1. Also the high probability point is at the 1 end, not at zero (although I can deal with the bell being "reversed", so that in itself isn't a problem, just an inconvenience of having to use `1 - f(x)` instead)

Comment: @Bohemian. Did you take into account the fact that $\text{erf}(-x)=-\text{erf}(x)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici as per the Q, I don't have any `-x`, only `0 <= x < 1`. I could stretch my random value over `-1 < x < 1`, but the problem is not that, it's that after 10's of thousands of random numbers, none fall outside the range of 0-1. With a sigma of 1; for a normal dist I expect 68% to be in the range 0-1

Answer (score 0):

**An easy approximation**:

By the central limit theorem, take $n$ random samples, add them, subtract their mean ($\frac n2$) and divide by their standard deviation ($n/\sqrt{12}$) and you get a random variable which approximately follows a normal law. The larger $n$, the better the approximation (but also the cost).

Comment: Exactly how do I take a *single* random value in the range 0 to 1 and using it produce a (obviously) single normally distributed value?