# Cdf of standard normal

Tags: normal-distribution

Evaluate,

> $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0.5365}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$$

In other words, how do I find $N (0.5365)$, where $N(x)$ denotes the $cdf$ of the standard normal random variable?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is YOUR question ?

Comment: It's square root $2\pi$ in the denominator if it's the cdf of standard normal variable.

Comment: If you're in a typical probability or statistics class, you usually use a table or a calculator. On R, you do `pnorm(0.5365)`.

Comment: If you have access to Matlab, use `normcdf`. If all you have is a C compiler that supports the ISO C99 specification, take a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891569/accurate-computation-of-cdf-of-standard-normal-distribution-using-c-standard-mat)

Answer (score 4):

You can make a series expansion for $e^{-x^2/2}$ at $x=0$:

$$e^{-x^2/2}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^6}{48}+\frac{x^6}{484}-\ldots$$

We want the integral

$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2} \,dt=\frac{x}{\color{blue}1\cdot 1}-\frac{x^3}{\color{blue}2\cdot 3}+\frac{x^5}{\color{blue}8\cdot 5}-\frac{x^7}{\color{blue}{48}\cdot 7}+\frac{x^9}{\color{blue}{384}\cdot 9}-\ldots$$

Without the blue factors the series is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

A formula for the sequence $1,2,8,48,484,..$ can be found using [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C8%2C48%2C384&language=english&go=Search). The result is $2^k\cdot k!$. Therefore $$\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2} \,dt=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)\cdot 2^k\cdot k!}$$

And finally

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2} \,dt=\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)\cdot 2^k\cdot k!}$$

If $x=0.5365$, already for $k=3$ one gets a good approximation since the approximated value is [0.704193](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.5%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5B3%5D%20(-1)%5Ek%5Cfrac%7B0.5365%5E%7B2k%2B1%7D%7D%7B(2k%2B1)2%5Ek*k!%7D), which is identical to the result of the [online calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the definition of [the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), you will easily understand that 
$$I(a)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$ The Wikipedia page also gives the Taylor expansion of it
$$\operatorname{erf}(z)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{n! (2n+1)} =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(z-\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^5}{10}-\frac{z^7}{42}+\frac{z^9}{216}-\ \cdots\right)$$ Using it, you then have $$I(a)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}-\frac{a^3}{6 \sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{a^5}{40
   \sqrt{2 \pi }}-\frac{a^7}{336 \sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{a^9}{3456 \sqrt{2 \pi
   }}+O\left(a^{11}\right)$$ Using it for different values of $n$ and $a=0.5365$, you would get 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I(0.5365) \\
 0 & 0.7140325334 \\
 1 & 0.7037649558 \\
 2 & 0.7042082568 \\
 3 & 0.7041930668 \\
 4 & 0.7041934919 \\
 5 & 0.7041934818 \\
 6 & 0.7041934820 
 \end{array}
\right)$$
If you prefer not to use series expansion, look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197785/solving-for-a-function-defined-as-an-integral/2197888#2197888) where are proposed two rather simple approximations
$$\mathrm{erf}\!\left(X\right)\approx \sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac {4X^2} {\pi} \Big)}\tag 1$$ $$\mathrm{erf}\!\left(X\right)\approx\sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac 4 {\pi}\,\frac{1+\alpha\, X^2}{1+\beta\, X^2}\,X^2 \Big)}\tag 2$$ where $$\alpha=\frac{10-\pi ^2}{5 (\pi -3) \pi }\qquad \text{and}\qquad \beta=\frac{120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2}{15 (\pi -3) \pi }$$ Approximation $(1)$ would give $0.704592$ and approximation $(2)$ would give $0.704193$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}  + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erf} \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} a \right)$ has undesirable numerical properties (subtractive cancellation). Preferred: $\mathrm{normcdf}\left(a\right) = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc} \left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} a \right)$.

Comment: @njuffa (By my calculations) using Claude Leibovici's  eqtn(1) for erf(X) and that erfc(X)=1-erf(X) then using your eqtn for normcdf(a) only works for a<=0. Claude's equations only work for a>=0.  Both your eqtn and Claude's equations give results which are symmetrical about a=0.  In both cases, inside the regions of error we can subtract the given output value from 1 to yield the 'correct' adjusted value. But when using Claude's eqtn(1) for erf(X) his adjusted cdf curve and your adjusted cdf curve are not coincident.

Comment: @steveOw Mathematically, the CDF of the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erfc} \left(\frac{\mu-x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=graph+cdf+of+normal+distribution), for example. For the standard normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ this turns into what I wrote above. I don't see an error in what I wrote.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks.  I'm applying Claude's $erf(X)$ equation between $-4<a<+4$ assuming $\mu=0$ and with $X=a/\sqrt{2}$.  Which gives the same value irrespective of the sign of $a$. I guess that is where my problem lies.

Comment: Claude's expression for $I(a)$ as a power series of $a$ seems to work (approximately). With mean = $0$ and $\sigma=1$ for $a=+/- 2$ to get $|\phi(a)|<1.0$ requires $n>=11$.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Simpson's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) to compute such function. There is no analytic exact solution to this integral.

Comment: Can you please show the details on how you use it in this specific . I'm very interested. I don't see any roots how can we write it in a way that Newton's method can be used?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Simpson's Method. I fixed my post. Thank you.