# Solving equation that contains cdf and pdf of standard normal distribution

Tags: probability

I have the following equation: $ x = \frac{1-\Phi(x)}{a\phi(x)}$, where $\Phi$ is the cdf and $\phi$ is the pdf of the standard normal distribution.

How can one solve for $x$? Is there an analytical approach? Or can this only be done numerically?

These might be rather stupid questions (it's quite a while ago that I last was exposed to this), but any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: First of all, have you tried to plot for example the 2 curves $y=a x \phi(x)$ and $y=1-\Phi(x)$ and see where they intersect in order, at least, to have an idea of where the root/roots is/are situated? A very coarse sketch shows for example that there are no negative roots

Comment: I am almost certain that there are no analytical approaches yielding an exact solution.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, thanks. I think, too, that the solutions are positive, but I was just wondering if they could be expressed analytically.

Comment: A small numerical computation gives, for $a=1$: $x=0.5969382659986477...$

Comment: @JeanMarie Really? It doesn´t seem very close.

Comment: @callculus As I see your result, I am at a certain distance... Maybe, I haven't taken the right definition of $\Phi$... I confess that 2 and 1/2 years later...

Comment: @JeanMarie"  How fast  time goes by ...

Comment: @callculus As said by Heinrich Heine: "Ich hab' euch im besten Juli verlassen / Und find' euch wieder im Januar ; / Ihr sasset damals so recht in der Hitze / Jetzt sei ihr gekhült und kalt sogar..." (Die Heimkehr, 1823)

Comment: @JeanMarie Wow. I didn´t expect that. C´est incroyable. I´ve to admit I have no idea about a similar lyric in french.  It gives my the opportunity to concern with german literature and maybe with french literature-but translated.

Comment: A slightly similar poem in french is the very famous "Le lac" by Lamartine (also in Romance times) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Lac_(poem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the series expansions. You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223296/cdf-of-standard-normal/2223472#2223472) how they can be derived.  Let $a=1$.

The equation is $x\cdot \phi(x)=1-\Phi(x)$. The equation can be multipied by $\sqrt{2\cdot \pi}$. It becomes

$$x\cdot e^{-x^2/2}=\sqrt{2\cdot \pi}-\left(0.5\cdot \sqrt{2\cdot \pi}+\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2} \,dt \right)$$

Using the series expansion the approximated equation is

$$x\cdot \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^6}{48}+\frac{x^8}{384}\right)$$ $$=\sqrt{2\cdot \pi}-\left(0.5\cdot \sqrt{2\cdot \pi}+\frac{x}{1\cdot 1}-\frac{x^3}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{x^5}{8\cdot 5}-\frac{x^7}{48\cdot 7}+\frac{x^9}{384\cdot 9}\right)$$

This equation can be solved with [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*(1-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E4%7D%7B8%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E6%7D%7B48%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E8%7D%7B384%7D)%3Dsqrt(2*pi)-(%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%5Ccdot%201%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%7D%7B2%5Ccdot%203%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E5%7D%7B8%5Ccdot%205%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E7%7D%7B48%5Ccdot%207%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E9%7D%7B384%5Ccdot%209%7D%2B0.5*sqrt(2*pi))). The result is $\boxed{x=0.751781}$

To check the result use calculators for the [pdf](http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=54) and the [cdf](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx). I get

$$x\cdot \phi(x)=0.751781\cdot 0.30073521=0.226087...\approx 22.609\% $$

$$1-\Phi(x)=1-0.77391=0.22609=22.609\%$$

It looks like that the approximation is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help. This is very interesting, and I will have a closer look at this. Quick follow-up question: The factors in the series are $1,2,8,48,384,...$ rather than $1,2,8,48,484,...$, or am I confused? (The context of my original question is a simple economic model, in which x is quantity in a profit function.)

Comment: @Carl No, you´re not confused. Good catch. Luckely the typo was in the last summand. So it doesn´t change the result much. I´ve  edited the answer, including the WA-Link. .If you find the answer helpful you can accept it