# First moment normal distribution but with...

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I've got the following integral to resolve:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\pi x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx$$

If it were from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, is a first moment of gaussian distribution and i know how to solve. But with this domain of integration I have some doubts.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Integrate by parts.  The result will involve the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: What is the context? At the first view it does not look very useful to calculate such a value.

Comment: If $\mu = 0$ then you can do the substitution $u = x^2$ to solve the integral explicitly. Here when $\mu \ne 0$ you can do the substitution $u = (x-\mu)^2$, but you will still end up with a term involving the error function, as Robert Israel mentioned.

Comment: callculus, context is asymmetric distributions.

Comment: @Diego You can use a series to calculate (approximate) the value, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2223472/144421) Some manipulations are still necessary. But I think you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

With $z:=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ we can rewrite your integral as $\int_{-\infty}^a(\mu+\sigma z)\Phi^\prime(z) dz$ with $\Phi$ the $N(0,\,1)$ CDF and $a:=\frac{\pi-\mu}{\sigma}$. We can express this as $$\mu\Phi(a)+\sigma\int_{-\infty}^az\Phi^\prime(z)dz=\mu\Phi(a)-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp -\frac{a^2}{2},$$where we have used $z\Phi^\prime=-\Phi^{\prime\prime}$.

Comment: J.G, are u sure i cannot simplify term near sigma? If i change domain of integration from a to infinite, i will have same result right?

Comment: @Diego If you integrate over $[a,\,\infty)$ instead, you'll get $\mu\Phi(-a)+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{a^2}{2}$ (because the integral on $\Bbb R$ is $\mu$). (My comment concerns integration in $z$-space, not $x$-space.)

Comment: J.G, thanks this will semplify all integral to zero, this was only half (first moment of skew normal distribution)